# Is this __import__ functionality correct?

Tags: python, import, celery, global

I have a package named `jiva_tasks`, which I'm trying to import via celery (using the `CELERY_IMPORTS` attribute of celeryconfig.  The import statement that celery is using is this:

```
__import__(module, [], [], [''])
```

Oddly enough, when this syntax is used, the module gets imported *twice*, once as `jiva_tasks` and another time as `jiva_tasks.` (with a period at the end).  Now, chances are good that celery *should* be passing in globals rather than an empty list, but this seems broken to me.  It seems odd that even if given the wrong arguments, `__import__` would import something that isn't a valid python module name.

I know that the way to fix this is to pass in `globals`, but I want to understand why I'm getting this result.  Is this a bug, or is there something I don't understand about how `__import__` is working?

**Update**:  It also seems to be working fine if I use `importlib`.

**Update 2**:  Here's the `sys.meta_path` and `sys.import_path` right before the `__import__` line gets executed:

```
>>> sys.meta_path
[]
>>> sys.path_hooks
[<type 'zipimport.zipimporter'>]
```

It doesn't appear to me that there's anything out of the ordinary.  However, I just now realized that the package I'm importing is installed using setuptools' develop command.  Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Creating an empty file "foo.py" and then creating a "bar.py" that says:

```
__import__('foo', [], [], [''])
import sys
print sorted(sys.modules)
```

prints out a list that only includes `foo` once, and not `foo.` or anything else with a trailing dot — so it's not simply the fact that celery is using `__import__` that is causing the problem here. Can you figure out what additional step celery is taking that adds the second module? (Or does a `print sorted(sys.modules)` right before and after the `__import__()` call suggest that both modules appear at that moment — in which case we need to look at what import hooks are defined at the moment of the import?)

Comment: I didn't think about import hooks.  Although `foo.` *does* seem to be getting registered in sys.modules when that `__import__` call is made.

Comment: If the `__import__()` adds `foo.` then let's look at the import hooks! Add to your question the output of printing `sys.metapath` and `sys.path_hooks` and, if you find any, try sharing their code with us.

Comment: Updated.  It doesn't look like I have any import hooks that are out of the ordinary.

Comment: I was going to ask what the value of `module` is at the moment that celery performs the import, on the off chance that it was equal to `'jiva_tasks.'` with a trailing period already, and thinking that such a value might inspire the Python import logic to first import `jiva_tasks` before trying `jiva_tasks.` with a period, per The Rules for doing multi-level imports. But I have just tried an `__import__('foo.', [], [], [''])` in my `bar.py` script above, and it works fine — only `foo` gets imported. `'foo..'` or more periods gives an error, but one is fine, interestingly enough!